# Display given distance using grid

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to angular9. I create a grid using  tags. Then I want to color grid cells given distance. ex: given 6 for distance, then need to color 6 cells from the selected cell. How I do that. Please give some instructions to me.

```
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

component.css

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
grid-auto-rows: 2fr;
}

.grid::before {
content: '';
width: 0;
padding-bottom: 100%;
grid-row: 1 / 1;
grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.grid > *:first-child {
grid-row: 1 / 1;
grid-column: 1 / 1;
}


.grid > * {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
border: 1px white solid;
}
```

Comment: 6 cells surrounding a seleted grid cell? If the math is right you can have up to 8 cells that are around a single grid cell, or 4 cells that share a direct border with it. Perhaps include some illustration to show us what you intend to achieve.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular ?

Comment: Grid space displaying the room. I need to display a given distance from corner (2d). one object has 6m from the selected corner. If one cell is 1*1, need to color cells an object can be staying.